# System is not asking for password as it should

Tags: software-installation

Suddenly I noticed that the OS does not prompt fo a password, whatever I do: installing or uninstalling, running terminal commands like update or upgrade, nothing.
This could be dangerous for the system security,
Can somebody help, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/sudoers` using `sudo visudo`, and remove the last line:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

then it should ask you for a password once again.

Comment: This is assuming that that line is the problem, but I guess we will find out from the OP.

Comment: @MatC then could you accept that answer?

Comment: But how did that row appear in the first place ? Did something go wrong in the system ?

Comment: Well Linux is a complex OS. There can be a lot of reasons why a config isn't correct, is not created, has wrong permissions... So answering this question is without a proper inspection of your computer is nearly impossible.

Comment: Sorry ADDB.I did not know anout acceptance. Now that I do, of course I accept the answer. Thank you again !